# How to skip Default Locale in Liferay Layouts

Tags: java, layout, liferay

Please find my requirement below :

**Consider :**

- Portal default-locale = English
- Some pages have names only available
  in French

**Requirement:**

Liferay doesn't allow page names without the default locale. But I want the page to be available only in French.

How is this possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try to set French by default. You need to change system-ext.properties.

```
user.country=FR
user.language=fr
```

system-ext.properties are applied due first Liferay starup, but you can manually change this in database.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I also have pages with ONLY English. In that case, I dont want the French locale to be added.

Comment: If you don't care about URL, you may use /en_GB /fr_FR (smth like that) in your URL and do some urlrewriting through urlrewrite.xml for desired pages.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you do custom field in pages through control panel called customLocale e.g. than through your theme you can use some code in velocity, get this property and if it's not null just set it. I don't know how exactly set locale through velocity, but i think it's queit easy. So to get customField value you need:

```
#set($customLayout=$expandoValueLocalService.getData($item.layout.companyId, "com.liferay.portal.model.Layout", "CUSTOM_FIELDS", "customLayout", $item.layout.primaryKey, true))
```

Where `$item` is your page in `navigation.vm`. So every page can be easily modified at every moment to change locale (not only French btw) and if you'd not need it just skip this option.